# What is $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 (x -[\sin x])dx$ equal to ( where [.] denotes the greatest integer function)

Tags: calculus, functions, integration

Problem :

$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0(x-[\sin x])~dx$ is equal to (where [.] denotes the greatest integer function)

I have solved it the following way by separating two functions: i.e. $x$ and $[\sin x]$

by integrating first function I got $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$ however I am not getting the second part please help.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: For $0 < x < \pi/2$, in what range does $\sin x$ lie?